# PyGame, Surface not showing

Tags: python, pygame

I'm trying to create a transparent surface over the pygame screen, unfortunately is not working. The main surface shows ok, but the surface that im trying to generate doesn't show at all.

```
import pygame as pg
from pygame.locals import *

pg.display.init()
h = 640
w = 480
_display = pg.display.set_mode((h,w))
_display.fill(pg.Color(0,0,0))

_active_surface = pg.Surface((h,w))
#_active_surface.set_colorkey((255,0,255))
_active_surface.fill(pg.Color(255,0,255))
_display.blit(_active_surface, (h,w))

while True:
    for i in pg.event.get():
        if i.type == QUIT:
            pg.quit()
    pg.display.flip()
```

Comment: If it's transparent... would you actually be able to see it?

Comment: @Roboinventor the line _active_surface.set_colorkey((255,0,255)) makes it transparent, and its disabled.

Comment: you should change your h and w variables to w and h.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
_display.blit(_active_surface, (h,w))
```

I think the last argument is the top-left corner of the position at which the blitting should occur.  Here you're giving (h,w), which is equal to the size of the screen, so blitting occurs off-screen.  Try with (0,0) instead.